# how to apply for loop inside in select query inside the configured datalist?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I have created a datalist with

```
GridLines="Both" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" BorderColor="Black" 
                    BorderStyle="None" CellPadding="5" CellSpacing="1" RepeatColumns="6">
```

I also have created database where their is column with productid which is the primary key of my table 
so in this as i insert the items they get insert in the datalist in the the horizontal columns,( incrementing the value of productid) and  as its limit exceed 6 a new row got created.But I want only 12 item each time i.e. only 2 rows.

I have added two Linkbuttons in the footer template of the page. I want as i click on the next button the items display count from product id =13 to 24 and  so on upto count(n).

I have configured my datalist with SqlDataSource1 and want to use the query statement like this

```
 SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM Products where ProductId&gt;=n and ProductId&lt;=m order by [Sports Name]"
```

i declared the m=1 and n=12 at the page load
 but when i run my page the following error occured

```
Invalid column name 'n'.
Invalid column name 'm'.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'n'.
Invalid column name 'm'.
```

now please help me to do this type of coding in my project.

Answer (score 0):

Try string.Format

```
SelectCommand = string.Format("SELECT * FROM Products where ProductId={0} and ProductId={1} order by [Sports Name]", n, m);
```

Comment: this statement iss generating parse error Parser Error

Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Comment: The SelectCommand is set in the .ASPX file, therefore you can't use VB code like `String.Format()`.